# How to search and replace under a regex pattern in vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to replace '-' (hyphen) in the file name to '__' (underscore)in a specific regex pattern.

For example, changing `/abc/123-def-xyzz.html` to `/abc/123_def_xyzz.html`.

I tried to use the regex below to match the file name by separating the text with hyphen and the text with extension. It matches `/123_def_`.

```
\/((.[^/]*))-+(?=.*\.html)
```

However, I fail to replace hyphen to underscore in this pattern. Using `$1_` will result in `/123-def_xyzz.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
-(?=[^/\s]*\.html\b)
```

Replace with `_`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2whxtg/1).

The regex matches

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=[^/\s]*\.html\b)` - that is immediately followed with

  - `[^/\s]*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `/` chars
  - `\.html\b` - `.html` as a whole word (no letter, digit or `_` are allowed right after `l`).